# Finding the extrema on a closed unit disk

Tags: calculus

Let f be defined as $f(x,y)= -x^2 -y^2 +x +y$ . The question is find the absolute extrema of $f$ on the closed unit disk $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ . I have found the maximum on $( 1/\sqrt 2 ,1/\sqrt 2)$ and the minimum on the negative of this point but on the unit circle . My question is what about on  the interior of the disk ? Any help or hints ?

Comment: Do you know Kuhn-Tucker theorem ?

Comment: I have not heard of that

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Take the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2+x+y$ and set them equal to zero. This will identify the critical values inside the unit disk.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding all critical points and then see which ones are on the unit disc.

$f_x=-2x+1=0\implies x=\frac{1}{2}$

$f_y=-2y+1=0\implies y=\frac{1}{2}$

since $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is on the unit disc, you'll want to consider that.

If you are looking for the global extrema on that region, then you ought to also check the boundary. Along the boundary, $x^2+y^2=1$, so

$f(x,y)=-1+x+y$

you can then parameterize this with one variable to find the extrema:

$g(\theta)=-1+\cos \theta+\sin \theta$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: If f is same as above and for points on unit circle how can i find the radial derivative of f and the tangential derivative of f. Can you help about this ?